# How Can I Find the Area/Vertices Occupied By a Widget in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

I have a 10 x 10 GridLayout with 100 Image widgets, and on_touch_down, I want the picture that was touched to change to a different picture. Since the touch signal will bubble through GridLayout and all its 100 Image children, I want to do a check in on_touch_down to see if the touch coordinates are within the area occupied by the Image that was touched. How can I find the vertices of the Image, or is there an alternative to my approach? Calculating each Image's four vertices as they are added would be rather difficult since I am stretching these Images.

Many thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.pos and self.size would have sufficed. How silly of me.

Answer (score 0):

The `collide_point` method looks to be well suited for this.

**For example:**

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    x, y = touch
    for child in self.children():
        if child.collide_point(x, y):
            do_something
```

**From the docs:**

Check if a point (x, y) is inside the widget's axis aligned bounding
    box.

```
:Parameters:
    `x`: numeric
        X position of the point (in window coordinates)
    `y`: numeric
        Y position of the point (in window coordinates)

:Returns:
    bool, True if the point is inside the bounding box.
```

..

```
>>> Widget(pos=(10, 10), size=(50, 50)).collide_point(40, 40)
True
```